TypeScript inference of array index elements and their properties
Typescript noob here.
Initially, I was playing about with a basic concept where I would have an array of unknown length (potentially empty), and then I wanted to split it into 2 new arrays. The first array would contain the 1st element of the original array, and the second array would contain the remaining elements.
    const originalArray = axiosResponse.data.arrayOfCoordinates;

    const [first_Element, ...remaining_Elements] = originalArray;

That looks like it does what I intend it to.
But, logically, I know that originalArray COULD be empty
And yet, my IDE only suggests that first_Element is of type Coordinates, and remaining_Elements is of type Coordinates[].
My initial thoughts would be that the suggestion for first_Element should atleast be Coordinates | undefined, but apparently not
And it's totally OK for me to access first_Element.latitude etc... rather than having to atleast say first_Element?.latitude
After a bit of searching online, I get the impression that Typescript deliberately is not making these inferences at compile time, but that I would indeed get an error if I tried to access first_Element.latitude at runtime (if originalArray were empty)
Okayy.... a little annoying(!)
But I thought, surely, if Typescript is "aware" in advance that the original array is empty, then some kind of inference could be applied. But that doesn't seem to be case:
    const original_Array: Coordinates[] = [];
    const [element, ...elements] = original_Array;

    const j = element.latitude; // OK to do
    const k = elements[3].latitude; // OK to do
    const l = original_Array[3].latitude; // OK to do

What gives? I don't really like this very much!

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. That means you should declare your types and values explicitly and try not to rely on third party code. Right now this is all essentially errors in my IDE because none of the stuff is defined. From reading your description I'd guess you're looking for --noUncheckedIndexedaccess but without a [mre] I can't say for sure. Please [edit] with a [mre].

Given a number array like this (just as an example):
const stuff: number[] = [10, 20, 30, 40];

The default behavior with TypeScript is to yield number when indexing into it:
stuff[2]   // type is 'number'

However starting with TypeScript 4.1 they added a new option noUncheckedIndexedAccess which will change that behavior if turned on:
// with noUncheckedIndexedAccess turned on:

stuff[2]   // type is 'number | undefined'

So if that's the behavior you want just turn that option on in your tsconfig.json.
Documentation here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess
